# using python parent classes and get error x is not defined how do i fix this

Tags: python, class, error-handling, parent

hi I'm using a parent class to create some functions and when running my function ribbon_three  I get error that x is not defined anyone know how to fix this

```
     class present(cuboid):
"""class for present inherits student class"""
def __init__(self,x,y,z,colour):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y
    self.z=z
    self.colour=colour
    super(present, self).__init__(x,y,z)
def ribbon_three(self):
    return 4*x+4*y+4*z

def ribbon_two(self):
    x=cuboid.perimeters(self)
    return x[0]+x[1]+15
    

p=present(1,2,3,"blue")
print(p.ribbon_three())
```

Comment: You need to use `self.x`

Comment: ``x`` => ``self.x``

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `self.x` instead of `x`, `self.y` instead of `y`, and `self.z` instead of `z`

```py
def ribbon_three(self):
    return 4 * self.x + 4 * self.y + 4 * self.z

def ribbon_two(self):
    self.x = cuboid.perimeters(self)
    return self.x[0] + self.x[1] + 15
```